# Creating column computing area in SF with SpatialPolygonDataFrame

Tags: sf, sp

I am attempting to add a column that provides the area of my HUC_12 watershed polygons to a watershed data set, but the only code online that demonstrates how to do this is using the raster library, which is incompatible with the sf package and tidyverse.

How do I create this in sf?

Here is the code I was using for reference:

```
library(raster)
shape = shapefile("~/Downloads/all_borders.shp")
shape$Area_sqm = area(shape)
raster::area(shape)
```

Comment: You could just use the `sf::st_area` function

Comment: Maybe you could try `library(sf); st_area(st_as_sf(shape))`.